# DataTable in Bootstrap not executing jQuery when record reach more than 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I used twitter bootstrap for my system. For displaying all of my data from the database, I used dataTables for it. I've added a new column as "Action" that contains 2 buttons, edit and delete. But when the record reaches more than 10 for the first pagination, all of the rows which contains my buttons on the second pagination and next pagination does not execute my jQuery code that handles the delete and edit function.

Can anyone help why is this happening? What are the possible solution for this problem? Really need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you bind your delete and edit function on `$(document).ready()` then the explanation is simple: at that point only the first page is available in the DOM and only the buttons on the first page will bind.

What you need to do is to rebind your events every time you change the page. For this, you need to call your binding jQuery code (let's say you have a method named `BindEvents()` that does that) on the `fnDrawCallback` event of your DataTable:

```
var dataTable = $("#YourTable").dataTable({
    // additional data table params,
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        BindEvents();
    };
```

See http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback for more details.

Comment: what does this BindEvents() function contain? How can I bind my data for every pagination?

Comment: How does your `jQuery code that handles the delete and edit function` looks like?